# Unable to apply order by clause on distinct select in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, order-by

The query is:

```
select distinct( Name )
from Students
where marks>75
order by Substr(Name,-3,3),ID asc;
```

This shows an error message:

> ```
> order by Substr(Name,-3,3),ID asc 
> * 
> ERROR at line 4: 
> ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression
> ```

Comment: `distinct` is **NOT** a function. `distinct (a)` is the same as `distinct a` and `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Comment: what do you think should this query return?

Answer (score 1):

You can't order by columns that aren't selected when using `DISTINCT`, or their alias.

To keep your order with a substring and another column, you will have to calculate them first (without `DISTINCT`), then just display the `name` while ordering by the other columns behind the curtain.

```
SELECT
    F.name
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            S.name name,
            Substr(S.name, -3, 3) substrName,
            MAX(S.ID) ID
        FROM
            Students S
        WHERE
            S.marks > 75
        GROUP BY
            S.name
    ) F
ORDER BY
    substrName,
    ID ASC
```

Comment: this query returns a result but I think one should clarify what Output the user expects. Why not use the MIN(ID) , Why do you think it makes sense to sort by MAX(ID)? Why should the ID influence the sort order at all? It seems that the OP makes an error in his reasoning. Even if one wants to produce the Output of this query, why use a nested select?  The following query will do exactly the same `select Name from Student where marks>75 Group by Name order by Substr(S.name, -3, 3), max(ID) asc`